# Concatenar columnas en una sola

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendoui

Necesito concatenar estas dos columnas en una sola:

```
columna1: columns.Bound(c => c.primer_nombre).Title("Nombre").Width(30);
Columna2: columns.Bound(c => c.primer_apellido).Title("Apellido"=.Width(30);
```

que esas dos me queden en una sola columna, ¿cómo puedo realizar eso? Es ASP.NET con un framework que se llama Kendo UI GRID.

Éste es el entorno de código en el que estoy trabajando:

[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez así?

```
columna1: columns.Bound(c => (c.primer_nombre + c.primer_apellido)).Title("Nombre y Apellido").Width(60);
```

Comment: jhoubert, no me funciona

Comment: Te da algun error?

Comment: no me deja cargar el grid

Comment: me dice que la sintaxis esta mal definida

Comment: Pega el error aca.

Comment: Me falto el punto y coma, pero de igaul me arroja un error que dice, 500 (internal server error)

Comment: Si, fijate que falta un parentesis: 
quedaría asi : `columns.Bound(c => (c.primer_nombre + c.primer_apellido).Title("Nombre y Apellido").Width(60));`

Comment: load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internar Server Error)

Comment: si ya lo del aprenteisis yo lo organice

Comment: columns.Bound(c => (c.primer_nombre + c.primer_apellido)).Title("Nombre y Apellido").Width(60);

Seguro que esta bien organizado?

Comment: si señor, ya intente con ambas opciones y me arroja el mismo error en la consola,  
load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internar Server Error), no sabes si depronto hay alguna forma de manejarlo por variables,

Comment: Estas usando asp.net , pero con que lenguaje en especifico? c# ?intentaste depurar para encontrar el error en el codigo?

Comment: En la web te debe dar el error 500, pero en el Visual Studio te debe dar el error real del codigo .

Comment: jhoubert mira es que tengo un gran problema, eso esta en asp.net, a lo unico que tengo acceso a las vistas y para estas utilizaron el  framework que es kendo ui grid, javascript, jquery  hasta donde tengo acceso no puedo mirar si es c#, esto no lo modifico desde el propio proyecto creado en visual studio, yo lo edito desde el editor de texto visual studio code. entonces esto hace muy complicado el trabajo

Comment: Si, ya veo.. bueno, puedes dejar mas codigo o un screenshot del código que puedes para entender mejor como funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando un template es mas sencillo.

```
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Width(150);
            columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Width(150);
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#=FirstName# #=LastName#").Title("Full Name");


        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesito de su ayuda, estoy tratando de concatenar nombre y apellido paterno en un dropdownlist de ASP.NET. Este es mi código y no funciona.

```
public void LLenarDdlCliente()
{

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FitposConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(nombre, apellidopat) AS 
        clientes FROM cliente", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        this.drpempleado.DataTextField = "clientes";
        drpempleado.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        drpempleado.DataBind();
}
```